# Spring fallback bean implementation

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-boot, autowired

I'm currently trying to configure **Spring Boot** (using **Java Annotations** and **ComponentScan**) for the following scenario:

**Scenario**

- There's an interface `MyService`.
- I want to provide a default implementation for `MyService`, let's call it `MyDefaultService`.
- If the component scan detects no other implementation for `MyService`, Spring should instantiate `MyDefaultService` as a "fallback".
- If there is a different implementation of `MyService` present, let's say `MyCustomService`, then that bean should **always** take precedence over `MyDefaultService` when autowiring a dependency to `MyService`. In that regard, `MyDefaultService` should be **recessive** (as opposed to `@Primary`).
- Ideally, there should not need to be an additional annotation on `MyCustomService` to have it "override" `MyDefaultService`.
- Ideally, no explicitly implemented factories or factory methods should be required.

**Question**

The question is: how do I need to annotate the `MyDefaultService` class in order to achieve this?

**What I tried so far to solve the problem**

- Annotating `MyDefaultService` with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyService.class)`. Didn't work because `MyDefaultService` is never used, even if there is no other implementation of `MyService`.
- There is an annotation called `@Primary`that solves the problem. However, it needs to reside on `MyCustomService`, a class that I try to keep free of additional annotations. Essentially, I need the *inverse* annotation of `@Primary` on `MyDefaultService`. However, I couldn't find such an annotation.

**Concrete use case**

I am developing a service layer in one project, and a different project will implement a web UI layer on top of it. The UI project has a dependency to the service layer project. However, for certain functionalities implemented at the service layer, I need to know which user is currently logged in at the web context. So I have to define a service interface for that in the service layer project, such that it can be implemented by the UI project. However, for testing purposes in the service-layer project, I need a default implementation of that interface. Also, in case that the UI project team forgets to implement this interface, the app should not crash, but instead instantiate the fallback bean and issue a warning.

Thanks & kind regards,

Alan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest writing an implementation of [`FactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) to do this. Your `FactoryBean` would scan the bean factory looking for beans that implement `MyService`, and if it finds one it returns that bean from `getObject`. If it doesn't, then it can instantiate `MyDefaultService` directly and return that. Your factory bean then gets annotated with `@Primary`.

So pieces like this (pseudo-code):

```
public class MyServiceFactory implements FactoryBean<MyService> {
    ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    public MyService getObject() {
        Map beans = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(MyService.class)
        if (beans.isEmpty())
            return new MyDefaultService(); // plus args, obviously
        else
            return get_some_bean_from_the_map
    }
}
```

and then

```
@Primary
@Bean
public MyServiceFactory MyServiceFactory() {
    return new MyServiceFactory();
}
```

Spring will automatically handle the factory bean (i.e. it will make the `MyService` object available as a bean for injection like normal.

This solution doesn't require any special magic, and it's fairly obvious how it works. You can also handle errant cases such as multiple `MyService` beans being declared.

Comment: `ListableBeanFactory beanFactory` in `MyServiceFactory` is null. How to work it out?